# match version of react, react-dom and react-native in one package.json

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-dom

what i want to do is ,in one project, i can use both react-native and react, so i need an idea of package.json, 
here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "reactNativeWeb",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "create-ios-bundle": "react-native bundle --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ./bundle/bundle_iOS/index.ios.bundle --platform ios --assets-dest ./bundle/bundle_iOS --dev false",
    "create-android-bundle": "react-native bundle --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output ./bundle/bundle_android/index.android.bundle --platform android --assets-dest ./bundle/bundle_android --dev false",
    "web-dev": "webpack-dev-server --config web/config/webpack.config.dev.js --inline --hot --colors",
    "web-prod": "webpack --config web/config/webpack.config.prod.js --progress --colors",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "15.5.4",
    "react-native": "0.46.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.0.0",

    "autoprefixer": "7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.0.2",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "4.4.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.1.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "fsevents": "1.1.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.6",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "react-dev-utils": "^4.0.1",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "3.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.7.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.2.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  }
}
```

and this configuration can run react.js successfully ,but it can not run react-native, so i need help, because react-native require react version of 16.0.0-alpha.12, but react-dom does not rely on this version , how can i find a proper configuration of this?

please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is a little unclear.

If you are trying to create a web app with react-native I think you got it wrong.
[react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) lets you build cross-platform mobile apps with javascript.

If you are trying to upgrade your react-native project you should look at [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html).

If you are trying to start a new react-naive project then you should use one of the ways mentioned [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html). You don't need to install react and react-dom manually.

Comment: one project and one package.json, run both react-native app and react web app, use npm run web-dev to start web app , use npm start to run react-native app, but now there is conflict between react-dom and react-native , because they rely on different version of react

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to do such thing but maybe you can separate folders like webapp and mobile and separate node_modules folders for each.

Answer (score 0):

thanks all. i fix it. successfully run web app and react-native app within on project, and here is the project:

[react-native-web](https://github.com/walkerXiong/react-native-web)